# In antlr visitor pattern how to navigate from one method to another

Tags: java, antlr4

I am a newbie to Antlr I wanted to know how to navigate from one parse the enter each method and I wanted the below implementation to be done using Antlr4. I am having the below-written functions.

Below is the github link of project. https://github.com/VIKRAMAS/AntlrNestedFunctionParser/tree/master

```
1. FUNCTION.add(Integer a,Integer b)
2. FUNCTION.concat(String a,String b)
3. FUNCTION.mul(Integer a,Integer b)
```

And I am storing the functions metadata like this.

```
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
        map.put("FUNCTION.add","Integer:Integer,Integer");
        map.put("FUNCTION.concat","String:String,String");
        map.put("FUNCTION.mul","Integer:Integer,Integer");
```

Where, `Integer:Integer,Integer` represents `Integer` is the return type and input params the function will accespts are `Integer,Integer`.

if the input is something like this

```
FUNCTION.concat(Function.substring(String,Integer,Integer),String)
or
FUNCTION.concat(Function.substring("test",1,1),String)
```

Using the visitor implementation I wanted to check whether the input is validate or not against the functions metadata stored in map.

Below is the lexer and parser that I'm using:

**Lexer MyFunctionsLexer.g4:**

```
lexer grammar MyFunctionsLexer;

FUNCTION: 'FUNCTION';

NAME: [A-Za-z0-9]+;

DOT: '.';

COMMA: ',';

L_BRACKET: '(';

R_BRACKET: ')';
```

**Parser MyFunctionsParser.g4:**

```
parser grammar MyFunctionsParser;

options {
    tokenVocab=MyFunctionsLexer;
}

function : FUNCTION '.' NAME '('(function | argument (',' argument)*)')';

argument: (NAME | function);

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

I am using Antlr4.

Below is the implementation I'm using as per the suggested answer.

Visitor Implementation:
    public class FunctionValidateVisitorImpl extends MyFunctionsParserBaseVisitor {

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public FunctionValidateVisitorImpl()
    {
        map.put("FUNCTION.add", "Integer:Integer,Integer");
        map.put("FUNCTION.concat", "String:String,String");
        map.put("FUNCTION.mul", "Integer:Integer,Integer");
        map.put("FUNCTION.substring", "String:String,Integer,Integer");
    }

    @Override
    public String visitFunctions(@NotNull MyFunctionsParser.FunctionsContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("entered the visitFunctions::");
        for (int i = 0; i < ctx.getChildCount(); ++i)
        {
            ParseTree c = ctx.getChild(i);
            if (c.getText() == "<EOF>")
                continue;
            String top_level_result = visit(ctx.getChild(i));
            System.out.println(top_level_result);
            if (top_level_result == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Failed semantic analysis: "+ ctx.getChild(i).getText());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String visitFunction( MyFunctionsParser.FunctionContext ctx) {
        // Get function name and expected type information.
        String name = ctx.getChild(2).getText();
        String type=map.get("FUNCTION." + name);
        if (type == null)
        {
            return null; // not declared in function table.
        }
        String result_type = type.split(":")[0];
        String args_types = type.split(":")[1];
        String[] expected_arg_type = args_types.split(",");
        int j = 4;
        ParseTree a = ctx.getChild(j);
        if (a instanceof MyFunctionsParser.FunctionContext)
        {
            String v = visit(a);
            if (v != result_type)
            {
                return null; // Handle type mismatch.
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = j; i < ctx.getChildCount(); i += 2)
            {
                ParseTree parameter = ctx.getChild(i);
                String v = visit(parameter);
                if (v != expected_arg_type[(i - j)/2])
                {
                    return null; // Handle type mismatch.
                }
            }
        }
        return result_type;
    }


    @Override
    public String visitArgument(ArgumentContext ctx){
        ParseTree c = ctx.getChild(0);
        if (c instanceof TerminalNodeImpl)
        {
            // Unclear if what this is supposed to parse:
            // Mutate "1" to "Integer"?
            // Mutate "Integer" to "String"?
            // Or what?
            return c.getText();
        }
        else
            return visit(c);
    }


}
```

Testcalss:

```
public class FunctionValidate {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "FUNCTION.concat(FUNCTION.substring(String,Integer,Integer),String)";
        ANTLRInputStream str = new ANTLRInputStream(input);
        MyFunctionsLexer lexer = new MyFunctionsLexer(str);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        MyFunctionsParser parser = new MyFunctionsParser(tokens);
        parser.removeErrorListeners(); // remove ConsoleErrorListener 
        parser.addErrorListener(new VerboseListener()); // add ours
        FunctionsContext tree = parser.functions();
        FunctionValidateVisitorImpl visitor = new FunctionValidateVisitorImpl();
        visitor.visit(tree);
    }


}
```

Lexer:

```
lexer grammar MyFunctionsLexer;
FUNCTION: 'FUNCTION';
NAME: [A-Za-z0-9]+;
DOT: '.';
COMMA: ',';
L_BRACKET: '(';
R_BRACKET: ')';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Parser:

```
parser grammar MyFunctionsParser;
options { tokenVocab=MyFunctionsLexer; }
functions : function* EOF;
function : FUNCTION '.' NAME '(' (function | argument (',' argument)*) ')';
argument: (NAME | function);
```

Verbose Listener:

```
public class VerboseListener  extends BaseErrorListener  {

    @Override 
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) { 
        List<String> stack = ((Parser)recognizer).getRuleInvocationStack();
        Collections.reverse(stack); 
        throw new FunctionInvalidException("line "+line+":"+charPositionInLine+" at "+ offendingSymbol+": "+msg);

    }
}
```

Output:
It is not entering visitor implementation as it is not printing `System.out.println("entered the visitFunctions::");` statement. I am not able to walk through the child nodes by using visit method.

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but you have "@NotNull" used in "@Override  public String visitFunctions(@NotNull MyFunctionsParser.FunctionsContext ctx)". In the generated file MyFunctionsParserBaseListener.java, it is declared "@Override public void enterFunctions(MyFunctionsParser.FunctionsContext ctx) { }". Try removing the "@NotNull", then recompile and run. It's likely calling the stub defined in MyFunctionParserBaseListener.

Comment: Also, you might want to add a println() call within visitFunctions() of the MyFunctionParserBaseListener.java generated file, so as to see if it is calling that instead of your override.

Comment: Below is the github link of project. I have removed @NotNull but still it is not working https://github.com/VIKRAMAS/AntlrNestedFunctionParser/tree/master

Comment: Thank you it's working!!How to accept zero argument in function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011569/how-to-write-grammer-in-antlr4-for-function-with-zero-argument

Answer (score 0):

You have a version skew between your generated parser and the runtime. Further, you have a version skew in your generated .java files, as though you downloaded and ran two Antlr tool versions (4.4 and 4.7.2), once without the `-visitor` option, then again with it. The source for MyFunctionsParser.java is in `AntlrNestedFunctionParser\FunctionValidator\target\generated-sources\antlr4\com\functionvalidate\validate`. At the top of the file, it says

```
// Generated from MyFunctionsParser.g4 by ANTLR 4.4
```

The source for `MyFunctionsParserVisitor.java` is

```
// Generated from com\functionvalidate\validate\MyFunctionsParser.g4 by ANTLR 4.7.2
```

The runtime is 4.7.2, which you state in `pom.xml` in `AntlrNestedFunctionParser\FunctionValidator`. There's `MyFunctionsLexer.tokens` defined in at least two locations, which one you are picking up, who knows. I'm not familiar with the Antlr build rules associated with the `pom.xml`, but what was generated is a mess (which is why I wrote my own build rules and editor for Antlr for C#). Make sure you clean the target directory completely, generate clean fresh up-to-date .java files, and you are using the right Antlr runtime 4.7.2.

Comment: Now its working but each time I run it is giving 
top_level_result-->null
 Failed semantic analysis: FUNCTION.concat(FUNCTION.substring(String,Integer,Integer),String)

Comment: Your visitor code compares strings using == and != operators. In Java, use equals(). Using a debugger would help you to clean up the logical errors in your program.

Comment: Thank you it's working!!, how to accept function with zero argument, 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011569/how-to-write-grammer-in-antlr4-for-function-with-zero-argument