# How to write grammar in Antlr4 for function with zero arguments

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm having function with arguments grammar like below lexer and parser:

**MyFunctionsLexer.g4**

```
lexer grammar MyFunctionsLexer;
FUNCTION: 'FUNCTION';
NAME: [A-Za-z0-9]+;
DOT: '.';
COMMA: ',';
L_BRACKET: '(';
R_BRACKET: ')';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

**MyFunctionsParser.g4**

```
parser grammar MyFunctionsParser;
options { tokenVocab=MyFunctionsLexer; }
functions : function* EOF;
function : FUNCTION '.' NAME '(' (function | argument (',' argument)*) ')';
argument: (NAME | function);
```

But in parser is accepting function with arguments or function with argument as function(nested function). I am using visitor pattern for validation. But now if I pass function with no arguments it is throwing error. How to accept function with zero argument in the above parser?

**Example For Working input:**

```
FUNCTION.toString(String)
```

**Example For Not Working input:**

```
FUNCTION.getTimestamp()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function : FUNCTION '.' NAME '(' (function | argument (',' argument)*) ')';
```

First of all the `function |` here is really odd. At the face of it, it would mean that you can call a function with only a single function call as its argument or with arbitrarily many `argument`s. But since `argument` itself already contains `function` as an alternative, it's simply redundant. So let's simplify the rule by removing that part:

```
function : FUNCTION '.' NAME '(' (argument (',' argument)*) ')';
```

So why does this not match function calls without arguments? Because the `argument` before the comma is not optional. The `',' argument` part has a `*` applied to it, so it can appear any number of times - including zero. But the first `argument` doesn't have any modifiers, so it needs to be there.

So how can we change that? Given that I just identified the problem as the first argument not being optional, one's first thought might be to just make the `argument` optional by adding a `?` directly after it (i.e. `argument? (',' argument)*`), but that would also allow constructions such as `FUNCTION.f(,X)`, which you presumably don't want to allow.

Instead you should apply `?` to the whole list of arguments, like this:

```
(argument (',' argument)*)?
```

That way it can match either "an argument followed by zero or more instances of 'comma followed by argument'" or nothing.